# How can we get ORIGPROFILEID in payflow for cancel recurring payment: paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro

My Concern is:

1. When we go through pay-flow Advance, it's not return Profile id.
2. As per fix my timing it's set recurring after one day.
3. I need profile id for Cancellation recurring.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1. Go with payflow advance 
   2. then make profile with below parameters, it worked awesome 

   "TRXTYPE" => "R",        "TENDER" => "C",        "ACTION" => "A",        "PROFILENAME" => 'profileName',         "ORIGID" => $orgId,         "START" => 'startDate',         "PAYPERIOD" => 'paymentPeriod',         "TERM" => 0,        "COMMENT2" => "transcationId:$orgId",       "AMT" => 'payment',         "PAYMENTHISTORY" => "Y"
```